# trying to make a GET request and return is PDF

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-hooks

i am trying to make a GET API request and the return should be PDF
this is what i am doing

```
useEffect(() => {
    const fetchOffer = async () => {
      setIsError(false);

      try {
        const authorizationToken = await AsyncStorage.getItem(
          'authorizationToken',
        );

        const res = await RNFetchBlob.fetch('GET', `${WEBAPI_URL}/client/loans/latest/agreement`, {
          Authorization : `Basic ${authorizationToken}`,
          'Content-Type': 'application/pdf',
        })
        console.log(res)
      } catch (exception) {
        // TODO: can do error handling here, or elsewhere globally for the app
        if (exception === 401) {
          console.log('here',exception)
        } else {
          setIsError(true);
        }
      }
    }
    fetchOffer();
  }, []);
```

however is throws an exception ! 
any ideas? what am i doing wrong ?
also worth mentioning that when testing the API on insomnia it works fine

thank you

Comment: see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Disposition

Answer (score 0):

i found the issue,

it was just an authorization issue
wasn't passing it properly

the code itself is fine...